# Uploading live video from user

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, video-capture

I need to capture live video from the client webcam and save it as a file (preferrably mp4) on a webserver. I currently use PHP, javascript and jQuery but am open to plugins and other API's.

Comment: Hoping you will never be able to do this, at least not without the users consent. It is however in the HTML5 media capture draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/ - hope they get this right no one needs to see me working in my underwear, lol.

Comment: At a glance, it does not look like it's possible without a third-party plugin at the moment.

Comment: Not trying to capture without consent. This is for educational component through video exchange, just trying to ease the users video knowledge burden. Any suggestions for plugins (proprietary or otherwise) that are capable would be appreciated.